# RSAT Win7 silent installation

Tags: cmd, installation

I'm trying to silently install RSATWin7 but it's not completely silent. At the end of the installation a .chm help file appears.
I used the following command "Windows6.1-KB958830-x64.msu /quiet".

Does anyone now how can I suppress the appearance of this help file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using a batch file and you launch this single command from a cmd prompt, if it then displays the CHM file then it's part of the executable.

```
Windows6.1-KB958830-x64.msu /quiet
```